# JQuery add/remove class based on menu item clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the below jquery to show/hide three separate sidebars. Currently the script only adds the class to the relevent sidebar, and removes it on another click. Firstly, my script doesn't seem like the most streamlined approach to achieve this, and I'd also like to ensure only one sidebar can be active at any one time.

As a bonus, i'd also like to add an .active class to the relevent menu item whenever it is applied to the associated sidebar.

Any help Much appreciated!

**HMTL**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="artists"><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
      <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="history"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<aside class="sidebar artists">
    <li><h3><a href="#">Artist Name</a></h3></li>
</aside>

<aside class="sidebar about">
    <h5>Biographical content</h5>
</aside>

<aside class="sidebar history">
    <h5>Historical content</h5>
</aside>
```

**SCSS**

```
/* Main nav */
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    ul {
        margin: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 35px;
    }
}

.sidebar {
  width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -50%;
    background: $black;
}

.sidebar.artists.active,
.sidebar.about.active,
.sidebar.history.active {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $( ".artists" ).click(function() {
        $( ".sidebar.artists" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});

$(function() {
    $( ".about" ).click(function() {
        $( ".sidebar.about" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});

$(function() {
    $( ".history" ).click(function() {
        $( ".sidebar.history" ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu40psjs/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<ul>
      <li class="artists"><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
      <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="history"><a href="#">History</a></li>
</ul>
<aside class="sidebar artists">
    <li><h5>Artist Name</h5></li>
</aside>

<aside class="sidebar about">
    <h5>Biographical content</h5>
</aside>

<aside class="sidebar history">
    <h5>Historical content</h5>
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
.active{
color:red;
font-size:25px;
font-weight:bold;
}


/* Main nav */
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 3px;
    ul {
        margin: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 35px;
    }
}

.sidebar {
  width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -50%;
    background: $black;
}

.sidebar.artists.active,
.sidebar.about.active,
.sidebar.history.active {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
 $('li').click(function() {
    var subMenu = $(this).attr('class').substring(-1,7);
    $("aside.sidebar").removeClass('active');
    if ( !$( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
            $("aside."+subMenu).addClass('active');
    }
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c7ZE4/261/)

Comment: always happy to help @dungey_140

Comment: how might I adjust the jquery above to enable me to have menu items that are not associated with an aside? In this instance I'd like to add 'News' as a standard link and when this is clicked it would be good to remove all active classes?

Comment: send fiddle I can't understand ur needs? @dungey_140

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102365/discussion-between-rj7-and-dungey-140).

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this)`

> For Example :

```
$(function() {
    $( ".artists" ).click(function() {
        $( ".artists" ).not($( this )).removeClass( "active" );
        $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @YoYo. This helps with the <nav> active class but what about the rest of the question?

Comment: @dungey_140 : can you test the above and tell me what else you want ??

Comment: It doesn't add a class to the relevant aside elements?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass) like this:

```js
$('nav li').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
       //first remove active class from lists and aside elements
       $('nav li, aside').removeClass('active');
       //add active class on clicked menu item
       $(this).addClass('active');
       //add active class on relevant aside element
      var itemClass = this.classList;//eg. artists active
       $('aside.'+itemClass[0]).addClass('active');//eg. add active on aside.artists
    });
```

```css
.active{
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="artists"><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
      <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="history"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<aside class="sidebar artists">
    <li><h3><a href="#">Artist Name</a></h3></li>
</aside>

<aside class="sidebar about">
    <h5>Biographical content</h5>
</aside>

<aside class="sidebar history">
    <h5>Historical content</h5>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great for the nav li items but has no effect on the aside elements?

Comment: Should work fine. Any error in your code? Check in the console.

Comment: No error, I copied your code into the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eu40psjs/7/

As you can see it effects the nav li items but not the aside

Comment: I was mistake. Updated my answer. As there would be active class in the menu item also you need to take out the first one.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much! One last thing, is there a way to allow the menu items individually to toggle the active class? For example, currently I cannot hide everything. For example, I click on 'Artists' to show that sidebar, but if I click 'Artists' again it will hide the aside too

Comment: Are you able to help with this? This is the final amend and I can mark as correct answer! Thanks

Comment: You want to hide all but active? if yes, just use css: `aside{display:none;}aside.active{display:block;}`

Comment: No, sorry. I'd like the .active class to toggle if a menu item is clicked more than once?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can add common class for all menu lis, lets say `menu` as shown in html below. register a click handler and toggle active class for sidebar with same class as menu li. Also remove class active for other sidebars.

HTML :

```
<ul>
      <li class="artists menu"><a href="#">Artists</a></li>
      <li class="about menu"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="history menu"><a href="#">History</a></li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    $( "li.menu" ).click(function() {
        var className = $(this).attr('class').replace(' menu','');        
        $( ".sidebar." + className ).toggleClass( "active" );
        //remove active class from all other sidebar
       $(".sidebar").not( ".sidebar." + className ).removeClass('active');

       //add active class to menu clicked
        $(this).addClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

**[JFFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eu40psjs/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    $('aside').hide().filter('.'+$(this).attr('class')).show();
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```